# Yii2: don't show footer for some views

Tags: yii2, footer, html.renderpartial

I want to not show the footer of a typical Yii view.
[image: View]

The function that render the view is very short:

```
public function actionPrintReport() {
    return $this->render('_myReport', []);
}
```

How can I hide it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create your custom layout and use it wherever you want to hide the footer

```
public function actionPrintReport() {

   $this->layout = 'yourNewLayout';

   return $this->render('_myReport', []);
}
```

go to `app\view\layouts` and create a new layout. ( copy the existing layout and just remove the footer from it)

Answer (score 1):

You could use renderPartial as below:

```
public function actionPrintReport() {
    return $this->renderPartial('_myReport', []);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for simply remove the tool bar  you should check in your view/layout and remove the footer part form the layout you are using  ..

eg for the default layout name main.php
you can simply comment the related  part  eg:

```
<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
    <p class="pull-left">&copy; my Copy  <?= date('Y') ?></p>
    <!--p class="pull-right"><?= Yii::powered() ?></p-->
    </div>
</footer>
```

instead if you want remove the debut toolbar  showd click on botton right side with  the yii logo

you must look in you config file  main-local.php or main.php  and commment or remove the part that invoke the debug tool eg: commenting the boostrap invocation

```
if (!YII_ENV_TEST) {
    // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
    // $config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
    $config['modules']['debug'] = 'yii\debug\Module';
```

commenti the $config['bootstrap']  the related  code is not loaded and use

Comment: it isnt about the debug toolbar but the actual footer **My footer** the image and highlighted section seems to confuse